.execute error with Supabase and Flutter (PostgrestFilterBuilder)
VS Code says that .execute isn't defined for the type 'PostgrestFilterBuilder'.
Here is my Code:
text_service.dart
import 'package:thrive/main.dart';

class TextService {
  Future<List<String>> fetchTexts() async {
    final response = await supabase
        .from('profiles')
        .select('community')
        .execute();

    if (response.error != null) {
      throw response.error!;
    }

    final data = response.data as List<dynamic>;
    return data.map((item) => item['community'] as String).toList();
  }
}

I tried to use .get instead of .execute but this also doesn't work. Can someone help me?

In the latest Supabase SDK versions, the ".execute()" method has been deprecated. Instead, you could directly use the PostgrestFilterBuilder object to fetch data.
`import 'package:thrive/main.dart';

class TextService {
  Future<List<String>> fetchTexts() async {
    final response = await supabase
        .from('profiles')
        .select('community');

    if (response != null) {
      throw response;
    }

    final data = response as List<dynamic>;
    return data.map((item) => item['community'] as String).toList();
  }
}`

